# Can I use RxJava to keep two collections in sync?

Tags: rx-java

Can I use RxJava to keep two collections in sync?

If I have a collection of Models. Can I keep a sencond collection of ViewModels in sync with my collection of models. The ViewModels can be constructed from the models.

Answer (score 0):

Single direction is pretty easy.  When a User Model updates, update the corresponding view model(s) that are subscribed to updates from it.  You can extend the concept the other direction as well. Logic can also be added to sync only certain fields (either by doing equality checks or by having multiple syncers per model)

```
public class User
{
  private PublisSubject userSyncer=new PublishSubject();

     public void setUser(User user)
     {
           ...//if multiple setters, do the following line in each.
           userSyncer.onNext(user);
     }

    public Observable getUserSyncer
    {
         return userSyncer.asObservable();
    }
```

}

```
 public class UserViewModel
     {
     User(User user)
     { 
         user.getUserSyncer().subscribe(User user->//update user data)
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looks good. But what about a list of Users? If one user is added or deleted?